# Unable to fetch data from Pinata (IPFS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, blockchain, pinata

I am trying to fetch the image and data which is uploaded to IPFS using Pinata endpoints but I am not able to load it and its showing failed to fetch at LoadNFTs(this is the function name),

here is the code for uploading the file to the ipfs :

```
    const uploadToIPFS = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
      
        const file = event.target.files[0];
      
        if (typeof file !== 'undefined') {
          const formData = new FormData();
          formData.append('file', file);
      
          try {
            const resFile = await axios({
              method: 'post',
              url: 'https://api.pinata.cloud/pinning/pinFileToIPFS',
              data: formData,
              headers: {
                'pinata_api_key': REACT_APP_PINATA_API_KEY,
                'pinata_secret_api_key': REACT_APP_PINATA_API_SECRET,
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
              }
            });
      
            const ImgHash = `ipfs://${resFile.data.IpfsHash}`;
            setAvatar(ImgHash);
            console.log("IPFS image upload succesfully")
          } catch (error) {
            console.log('Pinata IPFS image upload error: ', error);
          }
        }
      };
```

below is the code of MintProfile function :

```
const mintProfile = async (event) => {
        if (!avatar || !username) return;
        try {
          const formData = new FormData();
          formData.append('file', JSON.stringify({ avatar, username }));
          const resFile = await axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'https://api.pinata.cloud/pinning/pinJSONToIPFS',
            data: formData,
            headers: {
              'pinata_api_key':REACT_APP_PINATA_API_KEY,
              'pinata_secret_api_key':REACT_APP_PINATA_API_SECRET,
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
          });
          setLoading(true);
          const uri = `ipfs://${resFile.data.IpfsHash}`;
          console.log("error first")
          await (await contract.mint(uri)).wait();
          console.log("error second")
          loadMyNFTs();
        } catch (error) {
          console.log('Pinata IPFS URI upload error: ', error);
          window.alert('There was an error minting your NFT. Please try again later.');
        }
      };
```

On the screen  its just showing loading....

and this is LoadMyNfts function:

```
 const loadMyNFTs = async () => {
        // Get users nft ids
        const results = await contract.getMyNfts();
        // Fetch metadata of each nft and add that to nft object.
        let nfts = await Promise.all(results.map(async i => {
            // get uri url of nft
            const uri = await contract.tokenURI(i)
            // fetch nft metadata
            const response = await fetch(uri)
            const metadata = await response.json()
            return ({
                id: i,
                username: metadata.username,
                avatar: metadata.avatar
            })
        }))
        setNfts(nfts)
        getProfile(nfts)
    }
```

Comment: do you confirm that you successfully uploaded files to pinata?

Comment: yes , I can see it in the dashboard of Pinata

Answer (score 0):

when you fetch from pinata, you should add proper header. [from here](https://knowledge.pinata.cloud/en/articles/6848516-how-to-fix-400-errors-with-dedicated-gateways)

> There are other errors that have been proved to the IPFS team which we
> have reported and they are looking into it. In the meantime we would
> recommend using 'Accept':'text/plain'

your code should be

```
 const response = await fetch(uri, {
        headers: {
            Accept: "text/plain",
        },
    });
```

---

another issue is in the `results.map`. when you `map` the array, the first argument of the callback is each element in the array and the second argument of the callback is the index. should be like this

```
// since you are not using each element, we denote it by "_"
let nfts = await Promise.all(results.map(async (_, i) => {}
```

Comment: still giving the same error , when I am trying to test that uri in postman , its giving the correct response ,but here in react its showing that error and unable to fetch it

Comment: another issue is in the `results.map`. check the answer pls